# Drupal 7: Graphics included with custom module is denied access

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

With my module I have two graphicfiles placed in a folder at sites/all/modules/my-module/graphics
But whenever I try to access these graphic files through the browser I get an access denied error.

How can I access my graphics? They are used in my module so I need to be able to show them whenever my module is in use.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer as we don't know your environment, but here are some leads:

- Check your .htaccess at the root of you Drupal site or other parent folders for denying access to your graphics
- Check that the Unix user apache is using (www-data or whatever) has the right to read the file